# data segmentation

Tags: dft

1. Cosine signal of frequency 498 Hz is sampled 20 times in one period :   fs = 9960 Hz    Ts = 0.0001s    T = 0.002s  Ns = 20
   Resolution bandwidth = fs / Ns = 9960 / 20 = 498 Hz and because fs / 2 = 4980, we only need 10 frequency bins  / RBW’s (k).
   Using the DFT below in a spreadsheet

   ```
               N - 1
   ```

   Yk(K) = 1 / N   ∑   y(n)    ( cos (2πnk/N) - j sin (2πnk/N) )

   ```
              n = 0
   ```

   We can plot the results as a blue line in the attached graph.
   The red line is the corresponding graph I get when a build a simple model in Simulink/Matlab and observe the results in a signal analyser.

   The signal analyser in Simulink is setup with a word length of 20 and zero overlap. A rectangular window is used with a duration = simulation time =    T = 0.002s.
   If in my spreadsheet example I increase the no. of bins from 10 to 100 i.e. RBW now = 49.8 Hz, I get a lot more data and the resulting graph is exactly the same as the Simulink graph, even though RBW = 498 in Simulink ?
   I suspect the reason for the difference in the results is to do with data segmentation ?
   [image]

Comment: apologies about the detail. I am confused re. the power spectrum graph (red line) which is produced by Simulink (MATLAB). How can simulink produce such a smooth graph with only 20 samples ? In order to obtain such a graph using excel (blue line) i need to use at least 100 - 200samples